# Why does ExpressJS not match all paths on root app.get('/'

Tags: express

The following express routing matches `GET /` but not `GET /anything/else`.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('I only answer to /');
});
```

Is Express Routing not prefix-based or "deep"?

I know this works but it seems wrong:

```js
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('I answer to any path');
});
```

Comment: maybe `app.use((req, res, next)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get` must match the full path and stores it in `req.path`, whereas `app.use` matches a prefix and sets `req.path` to the path *after* the prefix. You could write

```js
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === "GET")
    res.send('I answer to all GET requests');
  else
    next();
});
```

`GET /anything/else` would be matched by `app.use('/anything', ...)`, but then `req.path = '/else'`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix although it's not as elegant would be:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) => {
  res.send('I answer to any path')
});
```

Make sure to add this to the end of all your Routing. Hope this still helps :)

Have a nice day

Comment: In that case, `app.get('*')` seems much more elegant :)

Comment: Thats what I thought xD

Comment: This idea gets `/foo` but unfortunately not `/foo/bar` etc.

Comment: I dont know if you still need this answer but I just remembered you can use this: Just edited my answer ^^